# Register an iphone App in a web service

Tags: ios, web-services, passkit

I had a look into a few airline apps around there. This posed some questions, I couldn't find an answer to and would like to ask you as well. My questions won't have any code but aim more at the procedural level of such applications.

The first thing I wondered: When I use an airline app for booking a ticket for example, I guess that my smartphone will be registered in a database on a web service somewhere. Usually the companies will send you push notifications for further updates. This would imply to me that the device token by the APNS is saved in a database table "devices" for example, such they could find my device later on and send me notifications.

To make my question clearer I think about the flow of the user that way:

1. Open airline app for first time
2. User is being asked if he will allow push notifications
3. User confirms
4. APNS is providing a device token
5. The web service of the airline will save that device token in their database
6. If an update is necessary, use the device token in the DB and send
   an update to the client

That would be the "easy" way to identify my users by their device token. But what would be the "standard" way of keeping track of registered devices?

To build upon my first question, I would like to expand this example a little bit. Most of the airline apps have the feature within the app to save a ticket as a passbook pass. I we take into account that the user has already accepted push notifications for the app he would be registered and listed on the web server with a device token for future reference.

As far as I know, passkit will send a web request to the airline server that they would have to parse in order to communicate with the passkit server. But in this request contained is a push token requested by the passbook app to receive updates.

Now I would think, that you have two different device tokens for the same user? I don't think you just can use the existing device token for pushing messages to the client in the database? 
So how do you solve such an issue? If you have a user in your database registered and the airline provides a ticket as passbook pass, how can passbook interact with this data correctly afterwards?

I hope I could make my point in my questions :)

Thank you

Comment: you want to associate a ticket with device or a unique user ?

Comment: The workflow would be as follows: 1) Register a new user on the server 2) Create a ticket with with a website and associate a user with the ticket. 3) the user associated with the ticket should get a push message and the pass send to his device. So I want to associate the ticket with a unique user

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what would be the "standard" way of keeping track of registered devices?

Whenever user starts your app you will get a callback

```
 - (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)deviceToken{

// associate device token with your username and send this to your server 
}
```

Please note that device token keeps changing . From [Apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/ApplePushService.html)
you cannot save a device token and use it for future reference. You need to update it for every run. Your server need to sync it's database of tokens.

Edit .. 
Flow of user

```
To make my answer clearer I think about the flow of the user that way:

Open airline app 
User is being asked if he will allow push notifications
User confirms
You provide device token and username to your server.
If your server now needs to send push notification it uses the most recent token and
send it to APN.
```

Comment: Ah okay. I have read about this callback. So the right way to do is, not to rely on the device token (how I would have done it) but for example create a UUID by myself for registration of the user in a database, and associate the device token to this account and update the token on every run. And when I want to associate a ticket to the user, I take my own UUID created for this user and receive the current device token from my database for this user to send push notifications?

Comment: you don't need a UDID , treat token as an address to device. you need to have a map on your server with key as your user id and value as device token which will be updated every time you app restarts.